# ruby koan? - cannot set variable same name as method name when mapping

Tags: ruby

consider the following code

```
def salt
  []
end

def pepper
  salt = salt.map{ |grain| 'ok' }
end
```

Gives the following result:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
```

Why do these circumstances exactly cause an error?  This is unexpected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your local variable `salt` is [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the method `salt`. Since the variable `salt` has been just been defined, its value is `nil`. You can remedy this by explicitly calling `salt` on the instance to get the method:

```
def pepper
  salt = self.salt.map{ |grain| 'ok' }
end
```

Comment: Interesting.  It still seems odd that they do it that way, rather than compute-then-set.  But it does fit with other cases, such as defining deadhead variables or for example: `a, b = [x]`, so a==x and b==nil

Comment: @PeterEhrlich Yea as soon as you do `foo = `, `foo` will be defined. Which means something like `foo = foo` results in `foo` being `nil` rather than a `NameError`.